# How can multiple matches be applied in dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiprocessing

I have a little performance issue with that problem:

There is a (3_000_000, 6) shape dataframe, call that `A`, and another one, that has (72_000, 6) shape, call that `B`. To keep it simple, suppose both of them have only string columns.

In the B dataframe, there are fields of rows where could be `?`, so question mark in the value.
For example CITY column: `New ?ork` instead of `New York`. The task is to find the right string from the A dataframe.

So another example:

### B Dataframe

| CITY | ADDRESS | ADDRESS_TYPE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| New ?ork | D?ck | str?et |

### A Dataframe

| CITY | ADDRESS | ADDRESS_TYPE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| New York | Duck | street |

My plan was to make a multiprocess investigation that iterates over the `B` dataframe and every each row I make a multistep filter, where first I filter with `A = A[A.CITY.str.match(city) == True]`, where the city is a regular expression `New ?ork => New .ork`.

So first I pre-filter with the city, after the address, and so on...

```
matched_rows = A[A.CITY.str.match(city) == True]
matched_rows = matched_rows[matched_rows.ADDRESS.str.match(address) == True]
...
```

Besides that, there is another really important thing: there is a unique ID *( not the index )* column in the `A` dataframe, that uniquely identifies the rows.

ABC123 - New York - Duck - Street

For me, it's really important to find the appropriate row of `A` dataframe for every each of `B` row.

The solution works but its performance is horrible. I don't really know how I should approach.
5 cores were able to decrease to ~200 minutes but I hope there is a better solution for that problem.

So, my question is, Is there any better, and more performance way to apply multiple matches to a dataframe?

Comment: Are the locations of `?` frequently repeated? You might do better to make dict mapping all the cities with `?` to all their completed names. Make a `set` of the complete city names, then map set the of cities with `?` to those. This should require far fewer regex lookups than the testing the whole 3M against the regex. (Don't know your data set well enough to know if it'll solve, but it'd be my first try.)

Answer (score 1):

As indicated by @dwhswenson, the only strategy that comes to mind is to reduce the size of the dataframes you test, which is not so much a programming problem as a data management problem. This is going to depend on your dataset and what kind of work you want to do, but one naive strategy would be to store indices of rows in which column values start with 'a', 'b', etc. and then select a dataframe to match over based on the query string. So you'd do something like

```py
import itertools
alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
keys = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(([c, l] for c in A.columns) for l in alphabet))
A_indexes = {}
for k in keys:
    begins_with = lambda x: (x[0] == k[1]) or (x[0] == k[1].upper())
    A_indexes[k[0], k[1]] = A[k[0]].loc[A[k[0]].apply(begins_with)].index
```

Then make a function that takes a column name and a string to match and returns a view of A that contains only rows whos entries for that column begin with the same letter as the string to match:

```py
def get_view(column, string_to_match):
    return A.loc[A_indexes[[column, string_to_match[0].lower()]]]
```

You'd have to double the number of indices of course for the case in which the first letter of the string to match is a wildcard, but this is only an example of the kind of thing you could do to slice the dataset before doing a regex on every row.

---

if you want to work with the unique ID above, you could make a more complex index lookup dictionary for views into A:

```py
import itertools
alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
number_of_fields_in_ID = 6
separator = ' - '

keys = itertools.product(alphabet, repeat=number_of_fields_in_ID)

def check_ID(id, key):
    id = id.split(separator)
    matches_key = True
    for i,first_letter in enumerate(key):
        if id[i].lower() != first_letter:
            matches_key = False
            break
    return matches_key

A_indexes = {}
for k in keys:
    A_indexes[k] = A.loc[A['unique_ID'].apply(check_ID, args=(k,))].index
```

This will apply the kludgy function `check_ID` to your 3e6 element series `A['unique_ID']` `26**number_of_fields_in_ID` times, indexing the dataframe once per iteration (this is more than 4.5e5 iterations if the ID has 4 fields), so there may be significant up-front cost in compute time depending on your dataset. Whether or not this is worth it depends first on what you want to do afterwards (are you just doing a single set of queries to make a second dataset and you're done, or do you need to do a lot of arbitrary queries in the future?) and second on whether the first letters of each ID field are roughly evenly distributed over the alphabet (or decimal digits if you know a field is numeric, or both if it's alphanumeric). If you just have two or three cities, for instance, you wouldn't make indexes for the whole alphabet in that field. But again, doing the lookup this way is naive - if you go this route you'd come up with a lookup method that's tailored to your data.

Comment: To make a lookup `dict` from the good ones of "question-marked" is a good idea, that was my first idea for me too, but the problem was getting complex with the demand of unique id. ( I've extended the requirements )

Comment: I'm not sure how that changes the problem. If you have a unique ID in every row and you find the correct row using the above method, don't you have the unique IDs you want? If you're matching on the unique IDs then dividing the dataset by the first letter of the ID might still take a long time because your match strings are long. Then you'll need to use use info about the IDs to make smaller frames. For instance if they all have ' - ' separators you could pre-index by the first letter in each field of the ID, so your index keys would be [columns, first_first_letter, second_first_letter, ...]

Comment: I edited my response with code to create a more complex look-up dictionary